# MS IotEdge eFlow: Connect-EflowVM error - wants password

Tags: azure-iot-edge

after successfull setup, some hours later when connecting with Connect-EflowVM
it fails, asking for Password.
Reinstalled, could start to work, after one hour the same problem.
Windows-OS: Server 2022
Connection from Win Host to IotEdge moduls works,
so it's no generell network problem.

Iassume a problem with openSSH keys or vsocknc service.
Any hints?

Following debug output of openssh
Compared this also with a running system, the error occurs when:  "Trying private key: ..."

`PS C:\Windows\system32> Connect-EflowVm -Verbose -Debug -ErrorAction:Inquire`

`$userName is iotedge-user  $vmGuid is 15E5DBA2-BCC8-4710-AF58-A85B9B5A1E81  $sshPrivKey is C:\Users\ext-gerald.kluge\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpAFA.tmp`

```
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec D:\\EFLOW\\vsocknc.exe 15e5dba2-bcc8-4710-af58-a85b9b5a1e81 22 

debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\ext-gerald.kluge\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpAFA.tmp type -1 

debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\ext-gerald.kluge\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpAFA.tmp-cert type -1 

debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1 

debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.9 

debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.9 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000 

debug1: Authenticating to 15e5dba2-bcc8-4710-af58-a85b9b5a1e81:22 as 'iotedge-user' 

debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent 

debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received 

debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256 

debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 

debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none 

debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none 

debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY 

debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:i3g5WMql7jdVdyQN/nMddlp6bowjIe/r7sKq9Uev8GA 

Warning: Permanently added '15e5dba2-bcc8-4710-af58-a85b9b5a1e81' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts. 

debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks 

debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent 

debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS 

debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received 

debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks 

debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory 

debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\ext-gerald.kluge\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpAFA.tmp  explicit 

debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received 

debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com> 

debug1: kex_input_ext_info: publickey-hostbound@openssh.com (unrecognised) 

debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received 

debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive 

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey 

debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\ext-gerald.kluge\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpAFA.tmp 

debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive 

debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive 

debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory 

Password: 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

wanted to connect with eFlow
```

Comment: please refer [this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/iot-edge/troubleshoot-iot-edge-for-linux-on-windows-common-errors.md)

Comment: @Sampath of course i did before

Comment: checked with "systemctl status sshd_v*"


(fortunately i had 1 remaining session open)



and found 

"Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for file /home/iotedge-user/.ssh/authorized_keys"

as cause for the problem

See too:
https://github.com/Azure/iotedge-eflow/issues/205

Comment: Hi @G.Kluge appreciate it if you could formulate a response based on your findings from the reported GitHub issue and paste it in the answer once a solution is identified. This would help other community members help find a resolution to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

> “Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for file
> /home/iotedge-user/.ssh/authorized_keys.”

This error typically indicates an issue with the ownership or permissions of the `authorized_keys` file in the SSH user’s home directory.

Posting the answer for community benefits.
Thanks **@sampath @G.Kluge**

Using this reference git [issue](https://github.com/Azure/iotedge-eflow/issues/205).

[image]

- Ensure the ownership and permissions of the `authorized_keys` file are set correctly. The file should be owned by the user and have the correct permissions.
- Verify the home directory (`/home/iotedge-user`) itself has the correct ownership and permissions.
- Check that the SELinux context is set correctly for the `.ssh` directory and its contents. Ensure the public and private keys are in the correct format.